# How to resolve ESLint error in defining `this` inside nested scope in Ionic Vue method

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, eslint, ionic5

I have an Ionic Vue app which uses the `slides` component to modify a reactive property each time it transitions. The pertinent code is like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { IonPage, IonContent, IonSlides, IonSlide,} from '@ionic/vue'

export default {
  name: 'Splash',
  components: { IonPage, IonContent, IonSlides, IonSlide,},
  data() {
    return {
      contentClass: 'bg-gradient-1',
    }
  },
  setup() {
    const slideOpts = {
      autoplay: {
        delay: 4000,
      },
    }    
    return { slideOpts }
  },
  methods: {
    slideChange({ target }) {
      const vm = this
      target.getActiveIndex().then((i) => {
        vm.contentClass = 'bg-gradient-' + i
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

This generates the following error:

`Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable  @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias`

The reason I'm using `const vm = this` is because once inside the `getActiveIndex` method, the scope of `this` changes and I can't modify the `contentClass` data property.

Rather than just blindly disabling the ESLint rule to allow `this` to be assigned to a constant I wondered if anyone was able to offer a better/proper solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that scope of this is changed?  You are using arrow function which should bind to this from outer scope. I am curios because I can't see reason why it should change.

Comment: Yes, very sure. Replacing `vm.contentClass = 'bg-gradient-' + i` with `this.contentClass = 'bg-gradient-' + i` causes an error ("unexpected aliasing of this to local variable"). Probably because the `slideChange` method isn't an arrow function; but I don't think it can be?

Comment: @Dan That sounds backwards :) Using `this.contentClass` wouldn't be aliasing `this`; rather it's `vm.conentClass` (where `vm` = `this`) that would cause the linter error. Do you have a link to GitHub repo that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes there is one solution. You can add the following object in your ESlint config file

```
{
  "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": [
    "error",
    {
      "allowDestructuring": true, // Allow `const { props, state } = this`; false by default
      "allowedNames": ["vm"] // Allow `const vm= this`; `[]` by default
    }
  ]
}
```

for more info also check on TSLint: [no-this-assignment](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-this-assignment/)

Comment: Do we have to add on the rules of the config file?

Comment: yes there will be a file named `eslintrc`

Comment: inside rules, it's not working for me but when I place it outside of module-export it's working fine for me.

Comment: ya place it outside itself

Comment: I too haven't mentioned that you need to place it inside `rules`

Comment: That's not a solution. If you work on an environment in which you have 0 control about linting configurtion, this is not something you can do

Answer (score 3):

It may also be solved by not using `data` and going all-in with the `setup` approach:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { IonPage, IonContent, IonSlides, IonSlide,} from '@ionic/vue'

export default {
  name: 'Splash',
  components: { IonPage, IonContent, IonSlides, IonSlide,},
  setup() {
    const contentClass = ref<any>('bg-gradient-1');
    const slideChange = ({ target }) => {
      target.getActiveIndex().then((i) => {
        contentClass.value = 'bg-gradient-' + i
      })
    },
    const slideOpts = {
      autoplay: {
        delay: 4000,
      },
    }    
    return { slideOpts, contentClass, slideChange }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.eslintrc` file on rules key add `"@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": 0`, for example in my case:

```
"rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": 0,
        "no-console": 1, // Means warning
        "prettier/prettier": 2 // Means error
    }
```