# error Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable - typescript lint error

Tags: typescript, eslint, lint, tslint

How to solve this typescript lint error?

```
const track: Track = this;
```

I am getting error on this line

```
error Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable  @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
```

Code -

```
import {trackMutePublisher} from '../Events/index';
// eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
export enum TrackStatus {
  ENDED = 'ended',
  LIVE = 'live',
}

// eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
export enum TrackKind {
  AUDIO = 'audio',
  VIDEO = 'video',
}

export interface TrackInterface {
  ID: string;
  kind: TrackKind;
  status: TrackStatus;
  muted: boolean;
  label: string;
  stop(): void;
}

/** @public */
export class Track implements TrackInterface {
  ID: string;

  kind: TrackKind;

  status: TrackStatus;

  muted: boolean;

  label: string;

  #mediaStreamTrack: MediaStreamTrack;

  constructor(mediaStreamTrack: MediaStreamTrack) {
    this.ID = mediaStreamTrack.id;
    this.kind = mediaStreamTrack.kind as TrackKind;
    this.status = mediaStreamTrack.readyState as TrackStatus;
    this.muted = mediaStreamTrack.muted;
    this.label = mediaStreamTrack.label;
    this.#mediaStreamTrack = mediaStreamTrack;
    this.#mediaStreamTrack.onmute = (event) => {
      const track: Track = this;
      trackMutePublisher(event, track);
    };
  }

  /**
   * Tells the browser that the track source is no longer needed. Updates status to ENDED.
   *
   * @public
   */
  stop(): void {
    this.#mediaStreamTrack.stop();
    this.status = TrackStatus.ENDED;
  }
}
```

I was going through this post in stack overflow but not able to resolve this. I don't want to ignore the error as well I can't change the most logic..
[How to resolve ESLint error in defining `this` inside nested scope in Ionic Vue method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65884506/how-to-resolve-eslint-error-in-defining-this-inside-nested-scope-in-ionic-vue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing below mentioned code.

From -

```
this.#mediaStreamTrack.onmute = (event) => {
      const track: Track = this;
      trackMutePublisher(event, track);
    };
```

To -

```
this.#mediaStreamTrack.onmute = (event) => {
      // using arrow function which should bind to this from outer scope track
      trackMutePublisher(event, this);
    };
```

Followed this link and got the fix -

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-this-alias.md